# Type a function that takes a tuple and returns a tuple of the same length with each element optional?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to write a function that takes a tuple and returns a tuple of the same size but with each element wrapped in optional. Pseudo code:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound=tuple[dict[str, str], ...])

def f(tup: T) -> Map[Optional, T]:
  # Dummy implementation
  return [None if ... else el for el in tup]
```

Here `Map` is a made-up, type-level function that wraps each returned element's type in `Optional`.

Concretely, if the input type was e.g. `tuple[dict[str, str], dict[str, str]]` I want the return type to be `tuple[Optional[dict[str, str]], Optional[dict[str, str]]]`.

Comment: Would you mind to shorten the example to a tuple of a simpler type, say just `int` instead of `dict[str, str]`? The incidental example of `dict[str, str]` makes this rather long, and due to invariance it is not that useful as a `TypeVar` `bound`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Use `@overload` to define a practically sufficient number of items and  a less strictly typed catch-all case.

---

There is currently no way to [unpack type variables from a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple) *and transform each of them*.

However, for practical usage it is usually sufficient to explicitly type cases for a low number of items. This is done using `@overload` to collect several explicitly typed cases. A less well-typed catch-all case for an arbitrary number of items retains some type-checking capabilities in any case.

```
from typing import overload, Optional, TypeVar

T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")
T3 = TypeVar("T3")
TN = TypeVar("TN")

# manually defined cases for usually expected item counts
@overload
def g(t: tuple[T1]) -> tuple[Optional[T1]]:
    ...

@overload
def g(t: tuple[T1, T2]) -> tuple[Optional[T1], Optional[T2]]:
    ...

@overload
def g(t: tuple[T1, T2, T3]) -> tuple[Optional[T1], Optional[T2], Optional[T3]]:
    ...

# catch all case when none of the explicit item counts apply
@overload
def g(t: tuple[TN, ...]) -> tuple[Optional[TN], ...]:
    ...

# actual runtime implementation
def g(tup):
    return tuple(None if ... else el for el in tup)
```

The number of item count overloads is a trade-off between covering actually needed case and maintaining the largely duplicated signatures; it is common to define up to about half a dozen.
The standard library (via typeshed) currently defines [up to 5 explicit element types, for example for `zip`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/2b20b70cf26fddab7588022c4129b5021fb88718/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1705-L1715).

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: You can't, unless you specify its size explicitly.

---

You are asking about type annotations that take into account `tuple` size, yet you use code examples that *specifically* disregard tuple size.

The usage of literal ellipsis indicates to the static type checker that the tuple can be of any undefined size. ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple))

Also annotating `*args` to a function with `T` is equivalent to declaring `args` to be of type `tuple[T, ...]`.

For the tuple size to be considered relevant by a static type checker, you need to explicitly define its element types:

```py
from typing import Optional, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def f(t: tuple[T, T, T]) -> tuple[Optional[T], Optional[T], Optional[T]]:
    return None, t[1], t[2]
```

Or, if they are different:

```py
from typing import Optional, TypeVar

T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")
T3 = TypeVar("T3")

def g(t: tuple[T1, T2, T3]) -> tuple[Optional[T1], Optional[T2], Optional[T3]]:
    return None, t[1], t[2]
```

---

If your tuple can be of *any* size and its elements have the same type `T`, then you can merely indicate that the returned tuple can also have *any* size (i.e. with no regard for the size of the argument tuple) with its element type being `Optional[T]`, as you already realized:

```py
def h(t: tuple[T, ...]) -> tuple[Optional[T], ...]:
    return t + (t[0], )
```

---

**PS**

If you want to abuse [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal), then a very crude custom generic subclass of tuple that receives a specific length as an additional type argument *as well as* requiring the length to be specified and consistent in the constructor is possible, but looks quite ugly IMO.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Generic, Literal, Optional, TypeVar


E = TypeVar("E")
L = TypeVar("L", bound=int)


class MyTuple(Generic[E, L], tuple[E, ...]):
    def __new__(cls, iterable: Iterable[E], length: L) -> MyTuple[E, L]:
        iterable = tuple(iterable)
        if len(iterable) != length:
            raise RuntimeError
        return tuple.__new__(cls, iterable)


T = TypeVar("T")
L3 = Literal[3]


def func(t: MyTuple[T, L3]) -> MyTuple[Optional[T], L3]:
    return MyTuple((None, t[1], t[2]), length=3)
```

Changing that `func` return annotation to `MyTuple[Optional[T], Literal[2]]` would cause a `mypy` error:

```py
error: Argument "length" to "MyTuple" has incompatible type "Literal[3]"; expected "Literal[2]"  [arg-type]
```

Also changing the argument for `lenght` from `3` to `2` would cause an analogous error (just the other way around).

But there is no way for a static type checker to notice an inconsistency between the explicit `length` and the actual number of elements produced by the `iterable` passed to the constructor.

So again, all in all, not a great solution. But I thought it was interesting and somewhat relevant.